# Failing to align side-by-side with bootstrap. One of the items is an angular component

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

```html
<form>
  <div class="row form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="communes">Sélectionnez une commune :</label>
    <app-communes id="communes" anneeCOG="2023"></app-communes>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="row">
  <div class="carte_metropole" id="carte_metropole" ></div>
</div>
[...]
```

fails to display the label and its selector the way I want:

(I would like to have:
Sélectionnez une commune : [Tapez le nom de la commune]
left aligned horizontally)

[image]

`<app-communes ...>` leads here:

```html
<div class="form-check-input">
  <input type="text" list="communesCOG" [(ngModel)]="libelleCommuneSelectionnee" (ngModelChange)="selectCommune($event)"
     placeholder="Tapez le nom de la commune">

  <datalist id="communesCOG">
    <option *ngFor="let commune of communes" [value]="commune.codeCommune">{{commune.nomCommune}} ({{commune.nomDepartement}})</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

I've attempted css classes and nestings I've found over the Internet, but eventually I'm confused.

---

@Arleigh_Hix I believe I've done what you suggested me, but it isn't producing the result you have in your demonstration.

[image]

Comment: `.form-check-input` is for a `input[type="checkbox"]` not `input[type="text"]`

Answer (score 1):

[`.form-check-input`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/checks-radios/#checks) is for `input[type="checkbox"]` not `input[type="text"]`.
You should remove the `.form-check` class from your `div.row`, replace `.form-check-label` with `.form-label`, and the `div.form-check-input` is not needed.
Make use of `.col-*` classes for a [horizontal form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/layout/#horizontal-form).

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/overview/#overview

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <label class="form-label" for="communes">Sélectionnez une commune:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input type="text" list="communesCOG" [(ngModel)]="libelleCommuneSelectionnee" (ngModelChange)="selectCommune($event)" placeholder="Tapez le nom de la commune">

      <datalist id="communesCOG">
        <option *ngFor="let commune of communes" [value]="commune.codeCommune">{{commune.nomCommune}} ({{commune.nomDepartement}})</option>
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<p class="mt-5">
  Below you see the alignment of a form-check-label always allows room for a preceeding checkbox, and will position it there if it is properly nested within the label.
</p>
<form>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">form-check-label (no input)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">form-check-label (input end)<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">form-check-label (input start)</label>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I've applied what you're suggesting, and I don't understand why it doesn't work the same than in your demonstration (I've edited my post to insert the result with your changes)

Comment: Did you notice my edit? I had forgotten you wanted them "side-by-side" until after my initial post.

Comment: it's angular thing.. @MarcLeBihan move the component selector _inside_ the `div` with `col-8`: `<div class="col-8"> <app-communes id="communes" anneeCOG="2023"></app-communes> </div>`

Comment: @traynor the label and the input don't support being separated by an Angular component? Ok. Then I will have to change my component a bit.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan no, `col-` class must be first child of `row`, and you have component selector, so it breaks. Alternatively, you can place the `col` markup on the component selector instead, but that's not a good practice in angular, AFAIK..

Comment: Thanks @traynor, I don't know much of anything about angular so I can only provide a solution as far the resulting, rendered Bootstrap markup.

Comment: @ArleighHix yes, your solution is absolutely correct about the markup, however, it does require some knowledge of angular to implement, as seen. But I went further and suggested a solution using just d-flex, which I think doesn't require angular knowledge, or even bootstrap form markup..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `d-flex` to align items horizontally:

```
<form class="d-flex">
   
      <label class="form-label pe-2" for="communes">Sélectionnez une commune:</label>
    
  
     <app-communes id="communes" anneeCOG="2023"></app-communes>
    
</form>
```

communes component:

```
 <input type="text" list="communesCOG" [(ngModel)]="libelleCommuneSelectionnee" (ngModelChange)="selectCommune($event)"
     placeholder="Tapez le nom de la commune">

  <datalist id="communesCOG">
    <option *ngFor="let commune of communes" [value]="commune.codeCommune">{{commune.nomCommune}} ({{commune.nomDepartement}})</option>
  </datalist>
```

Comment: Yes, it looks working. And this suppress all the `<div>` btw.

Comment: yes, and I think you don't even need form markup, you might perhaps use [figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) element instead